# error on line 4 at column 5: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml

When I used the code below I had the following errors:

The "positionfeed" element was not closed. All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag.
+

but when i deleted that to see if the rest of the code worked I got this error 
error on line 4 at column 5: Extra content at the end of the document

everything is in my positionfeed tag so im not sure why it is not working

```
@{
Layout = null;
@* http://www.juju.com/add-jobs/feeds/ *@
}
@model JobFeedXmlViewModel
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

@foreach (Job job in Model.ActiveJobs)
{
<positionfeed xmlns="http://www.juju.com/add-jobs/positionfeed-namespace/"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.juju.com/add-jobs/positionfeed-namespace/ http://www.juju.com/add-jobs/positionfeed.xsd" version="2006-04">
<source />DreamHire.io</source>
<sourceurl>https://www.dreamhire.io</sourceurl>
<feeddate>@System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString()</feeddate>
<job id="@job.JobKey">
    <employer>@job.Organization.Name</employer>
    <title>@job.Title]]</title>
</job>
</positionfeed>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
<source />DreamHire.io</source>
```

You have written the `<source>` start tag as a self-closing tag. This means that when the `</source>` end tag is encountered, it doesn't match any start tag.

Comment: changed that and I still have the same problem